Construction of fibre product of schemes
So I understand the outline of the fibre product of schemes, but I am trying to fill in the details right now and am struggling. In particular, I am struggling with the step where $X$ and $Z$ are affine and $Y$ is arbitrary.
Let $\{U_i\}$ be an open affine cover $Y$, then there $X\times_ZU_i$ exists for every $U_i$, we denote these schemes by $V_i$. For each $i$ and $j$ set $U_{ij}=U_i\cap U_j=U_{ji}$; we have that $X\times_ZU_{ij}$ exists because $U_{ij}\rightarrow Z$ factors through the open embedding $U_{ij}\rightarrow U_i$. Now there exist open embeddings $\alpha_{ij}:X\times_ZU_{ij}\rightarrow X\times_ZU_i$. We set $V_{ij}=\alpha_{ij}(X\times_ZU_{ij})$, and our goal is to glue the schemes $V_i$ and $V_j$ together along $V_{ij}$ for all $i$ and $j$. For each $i$ and $j$ we can view the maps $\alpha_{ij}$ as isomorphisms $X\times_ZU_{ij}\rightarrow V_{ij}$ as they are open embeddings. We then set the isomorphism $\phi_{ij}:V_{ij}\rightarrow V_{ji}$ to be $\alpha_{ji}\circ \alpha_{ij}^{-1}$ which is a fine thing to do since $X\times_ZU_{ij}=X\times_ZU_{ji}$ because $U_{ij}=U_{ji}$. It is obvious that $\phi_{ij}^{-1}=\phi_{ji}$, so we need only check that $\phi_{ij}(V_{ij}\cap V_{ik})=V_{ji}\cap V_{jk}$ and $\phi_{ik}=\phi_{jk}\circ \phi_{ij}$ on $V_{ij}\cap V_{ik}$.
I think I can show the third condition rather easily with the universal property once I show the second, but it seems that in every source I read people ignore the second one, which is weird because you have to show that for the third to even make sense. I am really however struggling to show the second.
I have thought that it should come from the fact that $V_{ij}\cap V_{ik}$ is the fibre product $V_{ij}\times_{V_i}V_{ik}$, and that $V_{ji}\cap V_{jk}$ is the fibre product $V_{ji}\times_{V_j}V_{jk}$, and then trying to get a morphism $\phi_{ij}(V_{ij}\cap V_{ik})\rightarrow V_{ji}\cap V_{jk}$ and show it's the identity. Or maybe go the other way and get a morphism $V_{ji}\cap V_{jk}\rightarrow \phi_{ij}(V_{ij}\cap V_{ik})$ and show this is the identity or something. Neither of these paths are working, but I can't think of another way to make this work...any help on this part of the proof would be much appreciated.
